# How to make Listview's Scroll slower?

Tags: android, listview, scroll

Scroll of my listview is very fast. I want to customize this and want to make it slower. I tried set `android:fastscrollenabled="false"` but it does not solve this problem.

My device is Samsung Galaxy S2.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Please use [setFriction(float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setFriction%28float%29) method of ListView. Because default friction value could differ between devices, it's better to use base value from [ViewConfiguration.getScrollFriction()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#getScrollFriction%28%29)

Example:

```
setFriction(ViewConfiguration.getScrollFriction() * 2);
```

Comment: Why the default friction value could differ between devices ?

Answer (score 13):

check

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setFriction(float)

```
mListView.setFriction(0.005f);
```