# Is there a way to make ListView scrolling behave like in iOS?

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, scroll

I have a ListView i want to behave like in iOS. in iOS (for example, the Settings app) if you scroll up or down and release the finger, the scrolling continues for a little bit and then stops. Currently in my ListView if i am scrolling and release my finger, the scrolling stops. With lots of rows it becames a problem because i need to be constantly scrolling

Is there a workaround?

Comment: I'm not certain, but I thought that was the default behaviour (at least for RecyclerView, the successor to ListView). I don't use any ListViews now; I recommend you upgrade anyway for performance & habit.

Comment: This post may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625876/how-to-make-listviews-scroll-slower/23626284#23626284